# How to make a relationship in the same table?

Tags: sql

So I need to make the same database in the image, but I don't understand what's happening in the "users" table, what is the relationship between "barbers" table and "users" table, and what is the relationship between ID and email in the "users" table ?

How can I do this database ?

[image]

Comment: I honestly think that your schema is wrong or that something is missing. There could be no relationship between `email` and `id` in users table, because one is an varchar and the other an integer. I guess you're missing a table that makes you able to join users and barbers

Answer (score 0):

This is my interpretation of the diagram:

(1) The line connecting Barbers to Users is wrong. There's no direct join so ignore it.

(2) That little line connecting id to email in Users is questionable. Nobody can determine the line's intent by looking at the diagram. We can pretend it's meant as some type of limitation, but really no idea. Either ask the artist or ignore it for now.

(3) Everything else looks right. Example: The path to determine which users go to which barbers is Barbers to Post to Payment to Users. So the query may look like this:

```
select whatever
  from barbers b
  join posts p
    on b.id = p.barber_id
  join payment y
    on p.id = y.postId
  join users u
    on y.userId = u.id
```